# The values inside the function body are different from the values passed in

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, multiprocessing

I noticed these calling sequence in a large program as below: (reverse order of the call stack)

```
// call step 1
std::vector<std::string> fieldNames = this->getUniqueMangledFieldNames(sigHierInfo); // fieldNames have "a"  and "b"

// call step 2
std::vector<std::string> SlFileIOBlockContext::getUniqueMangledFieldNames(
    const SlSigHierInfo *const sigHierInfo
    ) const
{
    std::vector<std::string> fieldNames(2);
    fieldNames[0] = "name";
    fieldNames[1] = "elements"
    slu::MLStructFieldNameUtil::getUniqueMangledNames(fieldNames, "signal");
    return fieldNames;
}

//call step 3
void MLStructFieldNameUtil::getUniqueMangledNames(std::vector<std::string> & names, 
                                                  const std::string & defPrefix)
{
    for(size_t idx=0; idx<numNames; ++idx) {
        //Mangle the name
        MLStructFieldNameUtil::mangleFieldName(names[idx], defPrefix);
      }
    ...
}
```

The break point is inside the for loop of the call step 3. When I check the values of the `names` in call step 3, it has "a"  and "b" in the vector instead of "name" and "elements". However, in the visual studio call stack window, when I check the values inside `fieldNames`, they are "name" and "elements".

So I do not understand how can this happen. Moreover, `fieldNames` in step 2 passed by reference to step 3

I thinkThe values in `fieldNames` of the step 1 should be random values because the call has not finished and not returned yet.

Multi-processing/Multi-threading? But how can the probably Muti-processing/Multi-threading make the values different in the call stack?

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber I think makeing the strings a reference should not change the content.

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber — a vector of references is not legal. So, yes, changing it makes a difference, but not in a good way. <g>

Comment: I see, forgot about that, removed the comment. If you suspect something like a not finished call, do release and debug version differ in output?

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber Thanks, actually, this is a sporadic failure. I ran 300 times to get only one instance having this kind of weird values. Seems this is related to database?